# Architecture parameter ignored by apt-get

Tags: apt, powerpc

I'm trying to download the package wvdial and its dependencies so that I can put them on a USB stick and install them on an old Mac with no internet connection. However, the command

```
sudo apt-get -d -a powerpc install wvdial
```

insists on downloading the packages for the architecture of the computer I run the command from (amd64). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

From [`apt-get(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8) (emphasis mine):

> -a, --host-architecture
>
> This option controls the architecture packages are built for by **apt-get source**
>   --compile and how cross-builddependencies are satisfied. By default is it not set which
>   means that the host architecture is the same as the build architecture (which is defined
>   by APT::Architecture). Configuration Item: APT::Get::Host-Architecture

The `-a` option is not honoured by the `install` option. With Multi-Arch, and the `download` option, you can use:

```
apt-get download wvdial:powerpc
```

This requires you to have the PowerPC architecture added to the list of supported architectures. Since Ubuntu only [provides packages for `i386` and `amd64`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wvdial), this is still not going to work though. You may have more success with manually retrieving the package from Debian as they support more architectures than just i386 and amd64: http://packages.debian.org/wvdial

Answer (score 1):

[You can find the powerpc deb installer here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wvdial/1.61-4build1/+build/3273144). Download it and use that to install it.

Regarding apt-get.  This works ...

```
sudo apt-get -d -o=APT::Architecture="powerpc" install wvdial
```

BUT it errors out cuz it can not find it ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wvdial is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wvdial' has no installation candidate
```

(using i386 does download it ;) )

From the [package list for wvdial here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wvdial) there is no powerpc option.